# Convertir letras/palabras a numeros en PHP

Tags: php

¿Existe alguna forma en PHP de convertir un número escrito en palabras a número? por ejemplo:

> once mil doscientos cincuenta => 11250

Comment: Esto te podría servir -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077600/converting-words-to-numbers-in-php, saludos.

Comment: ¿Se necesita algún límite? ¿Hasta el mil, millón, billón?

Comment: no uses etiquetas de javascript cuando lo que preguntas es sobre php... es mala costumbre hacer eso.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev existe algo nativo en php y en este caso es de palabras a numero,, con control de idioma.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si te fijas en las más recientes, hay una similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando la biblioteca [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) que está disponible en PHP y el argumento: `NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT` para despues utilizar el metodo [parse()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php).

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$numberText = "once mil doscientos cincuenta";

// Crear una instancia de NumberFormatter con configuración en español
$formatter = new NumberFormatter("es", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

// Convertir el número escrito en palabras a número numérico
$number = $formatter->parse($numberText);

echo $number;  // Esto imprimirá 11250
```

Prueba: [Link](https://onlinephp.io/c/797ed)

***Observaciones:*** aunque esto exista y se puede usar, no es conveniente si requiere del input de un usuario, ya que cualquier error ortográfico puede provocar que no funcione correctamente, solo lo veo funcional si se trata de comunicación entre API en donde una te dé el numero expresado textualmente y sabes que no habrá errores de este tipo.

Comment: Gracias, es para  reconocimiento de voz, en principio se soluciona si alguien dice mil doscientos cuarenta y nueve para 1249, tendré que modificar ya que si alguien dicta por ejemplo  doce cuarenta y nueve el código debe ser capaz de reconocer 1249.